# Undefined message when trying to fetch my javascript from the console

Tags: javascript

I seem to be getting a PromiseValue: undefined error for my "Visitor Count".

I am trying to get data from my API so it updates everytime i go on my website/visit the API link.
My Lambda and API gateway are both set up properly but I think there is something wrong with my Javascript code which is why i get this undefined message.

Is anyone able to provide me some insight why I am getting this message and how i am able to resolve it?

```
Promise {<pending>}
 __proto__: Promise
   catch: ƒ catch()
   constructor: ƒ Promise()
   finally: ƒ finally()
   then: ƒ then()
   Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"
   __proto__: Object
   [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
   [[PromiseValue]]: undefined

   Visitor Count:undefined
```

---

```
fetch('api link here')
   .then(function(sitevisits)
   {
       console.log("Visitor Count:" +
  sitevisits.visits);

  document.querySelector("#Visitors-text").innerHTML = "Total Visitors"+  
  sitevisits.visits;   
   });
```

Comment: What do you get when you only console.log `sitevisits`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch()` returns a `Promise` which fulfills with [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object. To get the actual data from the `Response` object, you need to call [`Body.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) method on it. This method also returns a `Promise`, so you need to chain another `then()` function. Promise returned by `.json()` method will fulfill with the data from the API that you requested.

You should also chain a `catch` block at the end of the promise chain to catch and handle any errors that might occur during the HTTP request.

```
fetch('api link here')
   .then(response => response.json())       // call .json() method 
   .then(sitevisits => {
       console.log("Visitor Count:" + sitevisits.visits);

       document.querySelector("#Visitors-text")
               .innerHTML = "Total Visitors " + sitevisits.visits;   
   })
   .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
```

For details on how to make HTTP requests with `fetch` API, see [MDN - Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

**Exmaple:**

See the following code snippet which shows you how to make an HTTP request with the `fetch` API.

In the following code snippet, a request is made to the `jsonplaceholder` API to fetch a single todo. When response is returned, in the first `then` block, we check if response status is `200` and if data returned by the API is in JSON format. If both these conditions are true, we call `.json()` method on the `Response` object othwerwise we throw an error to indicate that something went wrong.

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => {
    if (
        // check if response's status is 200
        response.ok &&
        // check if API return data is in JSON format
        response.headers.get('Content-Type').includes('application/json')
    ) {
      return response.json()
    } else {
      throw new Error('something went wrong');
    }
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
```

Comment: So does that mean in the (response) i need to type my answers? Also in the (error.message). Sorry if this is an easy question but i am new to Javascript.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by _type my answers_. You can access your data in the second `then` block.

Comment: What i meant was, do i just leave first `then` block empty? As in the way you typed it.

Comment: Data requested from the API will be available in second `then` block, so any code that deals with the requested data should be in the second `then` block but in the first `then` block, you could check if API returned the status code of 200 and if the requested data is in the format you want, for example in `JSON` format.

Answer (score 0):

You might simply see what the API return in the network tab and check the HTTP status, in the dom inspector it could be a backend issue, etc. or maybe better define the HTTP method in request.

```
fetch ('api link here', 
  { 
    method: 'GET', 
    headers: { 
      'Accept': 'application / json', 
      'Content-Type': 'application / json' 
    }
  }) 
  .then ((response) => { 
    console.log (response); 
  }) 
  .catch ((error) => { 
    console .error (error); 
  });
```